# How to send and receive multiple radio buttons value from jsp to jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, radio-button

I have list of questions, each question have 4 options Excellent, Better, Good and Poor these questions need to be rated by user any 1 option for each question. I am able to fetch the QID, Question from the MySQL database and list them in table followed by 4 radio button and name of each group of radio button for each question is assigned as their QID. Here is code

```
<tr>
  <td>Q. No.</td>
  <td>Questions</td>
  <td>Excellent</td>
  <td>Better</td>
  <td>Good</td>
  <td>Poor</td>
  </tr>
<%
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/feedback","root", ""); 
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs;

if(count>0){
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from question");
while(rs.next()){
int qno= rs.getInt(1);
String qname= rs.getString(2);
%>
<tr>
<td class="member"><%=qno %></td>
<td class="member"><%=qname %></td>
<td><input name="<%=qno %>" type="radio"  value="1" required="true"/></td>
<td><input name="<%=qno %>" type="radio"  value="2" required="true"/></td>
<td><input name="<%=qno %>" type="radio"  value="3" required="true"/></td>
<td><input name="<%=qno %>" type="radio"  value="4" required="true"/></td>
</tr>            
<%
}%>
<tr>
   <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
   <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
```

I am stuck here now, I am not able to figure how to send the value of selected radio buttons to the jsp page, where I have to fetch the valued and store them in database as 1/ 2/ 3/ 4 of each question.
Here the output of above code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPG9e.jpg)

Also I am submitting the view source of html code generated by jsp for reference -

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>How is your faculty communication</td>
    <td><input name="1" type="radio"  value="1" required="true"/></td>
    <td><input name="1" type="radio"  value="2" required="true"/></td>
    <td><input name="1" type="radio"  value="3" required="true"/></td>
    <td><input name="1" type="radio"  value="4" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>How is your study matrial</td>
    <td><input name="2" type="radio"  value="1" required="true"/></td>
    <td><input name="2" type="radio"  value="2" required="true"/></td>
    <td><input name="2" type="radio"  value="3" required="true"/></td>
    <td><input name="2" type="radio"  value="4" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>How your faculty language</td>
    <td><input name="3" type="radio"  value="1" required="true"/></td>
    <td><input name="3" type="radio"  value="2" required="true"/></td>
    <td><input name="3" type="radio"  value="3" required="true"/></td>
    <td><input name="3" type="radio"  value="4" required="true"/></td>
</tr>
```

Kindly give some code/ suggestion/ guidance.

Thank you to all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After waiting for 1 hour, but I was trying in this period and found the how I can pass and retrieve values here is the solution -
I added 1 hidden field in my jsp where radio buttons are displayed, this hidden field will give me number of rows like this -

```
int totque=0;    
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from question");
while(rs.next()){
   ++totque;
int qno= rs.getInt(1);
String qname= rs.getString(2);
String qnos=Integer.toString(qno);
%>
<tr>
    <td class="member"><%=qnos %></td>
    <td class="member"><%=qname %></td>
    <td><input name="<%=qnos %>" type="radio"  value="1" required/></td>
    <td><input name="<%=qnos %>" type="radio"  value="2" required/></td>
    <td><input name="<%=qnos %>" type="radio"  value="3" required/></td>
    <td><input name="<%=qnos %>" type="radio"  value="4" required/></td>
</tr>
<%
}%>
<tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td><input type="hidden" id="thisField" name="inputName" value="<%=totque %>"></td>
   <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
   <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
```

Then fetch the value of hidden field and the radio buttons values on another jsp page.

```
<% String hidden = request.getParameter("inputName"); 
    int j=Integer.parseInt(hidden);
    %>

    <%    String s[] = new String[j];
    int k=0;
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++){
        k++;
    s[i] = request.getParameter(Integer.toString(k)); 
    out.println(s[i]);
    }%>
```

I got the fine output as per my requirement. May this code help others.
And thank you for not replying my post, this make me learn lots of facts.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to do this. You can assign same id lets say id="rb" to all the radio buttons and assign each a value using value="here you can use relevant filed from the DB". You will have a array of strings named cb whose values are assigned ffrom the DB field. Then on the next jsp retrieve the String[] cb using request.getParameter.Values("cb").